# CM Advanced Search Limited to 1000 results?

Tags: 2013

Is the CM Advanced Search feature limited to 1000 results?  If so, is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `[Tridion Home]\solr-home\tridion\conf\solrconfig.xml` file, the standard request handler is set to return a maximum of 1000 rows.

```
  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="defType">complex</str>
      <int name="rows">1000</int>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

When you specify the `Show Results` Advanced Search setting, it overrides this with a `&rows=XXX` querystring setting in the request to Solr (the search tool the the Tridion CME uses under the hood).

If you expect your CME queries to need to return more than 1000 results, the `rows`  setting can be increased.

You may need to restart Solr's application server, or run the [Reload](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) command to get changes to take effect.

Comment: Have you ever tried to update to 10,000 rows for search results? in Web 8?

Comment: I’ve not tried this in Web 8+, I’m afraid. I don’t think that the underlying search architecture has changed much from 2013 though, so I don’t see any reason why it shouldn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is not the case as I have verified search for 10000 records as well. If you are facing some issue for more than 1000 result, then share the scenario and issue that you are facing.

Comment: "Showing All 1000 results, sorted by Best Match".  That is for an advanced search of components with a "modified" date range.  If I shrink the date range, I still get a 1000 results, even if some of the 1st results from the  components search were in the part of the date range I truncated.