# Get Tridion Items based on Modified date

Tags: core-service, content-manager, 2011-sp1, search

We are looking for a tool which will list all Tridion Items such as Publications, Folders, Structure Groups Schemas, Components, Component Templates, Pages, Categories and Keywords modified after particular date. (or modified between two dates)

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1

Is there any out of the box feature/custom tool/power tool available for this?

We can use Tridion search for this, but we don't know search is configured and working (As of now we don't have access to CMS environment)

Comment: Search is your friend...check the documentation on updating the search Index and make sure both Search Windows Services are running on the server...  Also - make a Virtual Folder after you fine-tune your search and call it 'LastModifiedSince1Month'

Answer (score 3):

You are right, you could use [Advanced Search](http://blog.stage-two.com/2014/02/10/sdl-tridion-advanced-search/) to get all of the items and sort them by modified date. However, if you're searching the whole CMS then you may need to [increase the limit on the number of items returned](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/7620/71) and this relies on your CMS search index being up to date and configured correctly.

If you have access to the [Core Service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90), then you could write a client for this to iterate through all of the items within your CMS, store them and then sort them by modified date.

This would need some custom coding though. You may want to take a look at the [Count Items Tridion PowerTool](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/CountItems) as as a starting point for iterating through all of the items.

Comment: Keep in mind that search will not return you info for publications